# Requiem/Frostfall causing constant Stamina loss

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I just reinstalled Skyrim and have installed a couple of mods alongside it, including both Requiem and Frostfall for a more immersive/hardcore experience.

However, something is *constantly* draining my Stamina for no apparent reason. I have checked my active magic effects and nothing indicates that I should be losing Stamina. This results in my Stamina being empty *all* the time, which causes me to drop my weapons after 1/2 hits. It's getting really frustrating; I don't think this is how the mods should work. Does anyone know what went wrong? This is my load order:

```
00  Skyrim.esm
01  Update.esm
**  Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp  [Version 2.0.0a]
**  Unofficial Dawnguard Patch.esp  [Version 2.0.0]
**  Unofficial Dragonborn Patch.esp  [Version 2.0.0]
02  Skyrim Project Optimization - Full Version.esm
03  Lanterns Of Skyrim - All In One - Main.esm
04  SkyMoMod.esm
05  SPIKE.esm
06  HighResTexturePack01.esp
07  HighResTexturePack02.esp
08  HighResTexturePack03.esp
09  Unofficial High Resolution Patch.esp  [Version 1.1.3a]
0A  Chesko_Frostfall.esp
0B  Better Dynamic Snow.esp
0C  Clanking Armor.esp
0D  Improved Combat Sounds v2.2.esp
0E  randomthunder.esp
0F  Dual Sheath Redux.esp
10  Skyrim Immersive Creatures.esp  [Version v6.1.3]
11  Skyrim Immersive Creatures - DLC2.esp  [Version v6.1.3]
12  Chesko_LoreBasedLoadingScreens.esp
13  Footprints.esp
14  RaceMenu.esp
15  RaceMenuPlugin.esp
16  WetandCold.esp
17  SkyUI.esp
18  MinimalHUD.esp
19  hothtrooper44_ArmorCompilation.esp
1A  Immersive Weapons.esp
1B  Unique Uniques.esp  [Version 1.5]
1C  Dr_Bandolier.esp
1D  ImmersiveArmorsNPCs.esp
1E  Requiem.esp
1F  BetterQuestObjectives.esp
20  BetterQuestObjectives-Dawnguard.esp
21  BetterQuestObjectives-Hearthfire.esp
22  BetterQuestObjectives-RequiemPatch.esp
23  Disable Fast Travel DAWNGUARD.esp
24  Headtracking.esp
25  SkyTEST-RealisticAnimals&Predators.esp
26  dD - Enhanced Blood Main.esp
27  The Joy of Perspective.esp
28  BFT Ships and Carriages - HF.esp
29  SoS - The Dungeons.esp  [Version 1.23]
2A  SoS - The Wilds.esp  [Version 1.13]
2B  SoS - Civilization.esp  [Version 1.02]
2C  EnhancedLightsandFX.esp
2D  Realistic Lighting.esp
2E  Realistic Lighting Patcher.esp
2F  RealisticCarryWeight.esp
30  Apocalypse - The Spell Package.esp
31  Dwemerverse - Dwarven Magic Package.esp
32  ForgottenMagic_Redone.esp
33  The Dance of Death - Ultimate Edition.esp
34  Beards.esp
35  TheEyesOfBeauty.esp  [Version 9]
36  3DNPC.esp
37  Alternate Start - Live Another Life.esp  [Version 2.3.3b]
38  BetterQuestObjectives-AlternateStartPatch.esp
39  dD - Realistic Ragdoll Force - Realistic.esp
3A  getSnowy.esp
3B  Bashed Patch, 0.esp
3C  Automatic Variants.esp
3D  ASIS-Dependency.esp
3E  ASIS.esp
3F  Dual Sheath Redux Patch.esp
```

Comment: Have you tried running [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/6/?)?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the reason for losing Stamina constantly wasn't a mod conflict or anything, it was my own stupidity. I didn't know that wearing Heavy armor in Requiem caused a Stamina drain if you did not spend any perks on it. I was wearing a Heavy helmet. Removing that got rid of the Stamina drain and it's all good now!

Answer (score 0):

The frostfall mod is probably what is causing this, as per the [manual](https://sites.google.com/site/skyrimsurvivorseries/frostfall/survival-basics-exposure):

> Increasing exposure will cause your character's condition to gradually worsen. You will be automatically notified if your condition changes.
>
> *snip*
>
> -20 to -39: Chilly: -10% Health, Stamina, and Magicka Regeneration.
>
> -40 to -59: Very Cold: -25% Health, Magicka, and Stamina Regeneration; -10 Archery, One-handed, Two-handed, Block, and all Magicka skills; -30 Pickpocket and Lockpicking.
>
> *snip*

Try using the lesser power weather sense to see your current exposure (select it in magic and press Z).

There are various ways to stay warm and dry (more info in the manual) but the main thing is to wear cloths and to seek shelter during blizzards. Food and torches or other sources of fire (not destruction spells on yourself unfortunately) can help you survive during bad weather.

Comment: Frostfall doesn't *drain* stamina, though.

Comment: Negative stamina regeneration should drain it I believe?

Comment: when you take away in percentages, it should never go to negative side, but it's a possibility.

Comment: -25% regen just means it regenerates 25% slower.